# How can I create PDF documentation with cut-and-paste-able code snippets?

Tags: pdf, documentation

I've tried using LaTeX and DocBook for documenting programming tools, to get PDF output. What I've found is that these tools are excellent in some ways - easily versioned, and generating very usable PDF manuals. But there is a serious flaw. Code-snippets cannot simply be cut-and-pasted out of the PDF.

With DocBook, the problem is the loss of whitespace - mostly for indentation, but any repeated spaces seem to get stripped out. So, once you paste the snippet into a text editor, you'll need to clean up the indentation and vertical alignment. Not too much hassle for two or three lines, but it quickly gets annoying.

With LaTeX - well, it's a mess. The following was taken from a PDF generated using the LaTeX in MikTeX 2.8.

```
node myclas s
f f i e l d f i e l d 0 1 : i n t ;
f i e l d f i e l d 0 2 : ” char ” ;
g;
```

The intended example is...

```
node myclass
{
  field field01 : int;
  field field02 : "char*";
};
```

Other than the fact LaTeX plays with the quotes, the intended form is what you see in Adobe Reader - but not much like what you get from a cut-and-paste. Don't ask me what's going on with the spaces, or why the braces turned into letters, or what happened to the asterisk - I don't know!

Mostly, I've noticed these things playing with ways of keeping my own personal notes, and just went back to other ways. Some notes are in HTML or plain text, so I can version them. Others are in an old Journal program I've used for years. But I've written a tool that I may want to release soon - and I'll want to include a usable PDF manual, which will need to include examples.

So - is there a way of creating PDF documentation where the code snippets can be easily cut-and-pasted? Preferably a way that allows me to keep "sources" in versioned text files.

**EDIT**

Any solution must be portable. I will need to use it on Linux and on Windows XP.

**EDIT**

It looks like this may be impossible.

I've tried printing from Notepad++ to the Adobe Acrobat Pro 7 printer driver. The resulting document looked fine, but cutting and pasting gave the same missing whitespace problems as occur with DocBook.

I tried using the touchup text tool in Acrobat Pro to add leading spaces. These are preserved when you save and reload - but when you select text normally in acrobat, they aren't included. You can only cut-and-paste including those spaces using the touchup text tool, so far as I can tell, which is obviously not included in reader.

In other words, this looks like a fundamental limitation - not of the PDF format itself so much as the tools that work with it. There appears to be a general assumption at work here that whitespace is insignificant - which for my purposes obviously isn't true.

**EDIT**

One solution may be a "text field". I can add these fairly easily using Acrobat Pro, can set a fixed width font, enter multiple lines of text and make the field read only. In Acrobat Pro 7, the text in the field then isn't selectable - but in Reader 9 it *is* selectable and everything is preserved when you cut and paste.

The question is - can text fields be generated directly using some kind of markup language that is usable to create complete manuals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest [enscript](http://www.markkurossi.com/genscript/). I use it for producing archives and documentations.
Also, you can merge multiple source codes ps'ed with enscript into another pdf.

Comment: I've just had a look, but I should have said that I'll need to run it on Windows. I know there's a Windows port, but it's the first time I've ever seen a Windows port that assumes it'll be running on a Unix-like system. Even the binary download assumes a Unix filesystem structure, only includes the original Unix-based install instructions, etc. I've really had enough of these it's-a-challenge-just-to-install-the-damned-thing programs, so this isn't going to work for me.

Comment: OK, then I'd suggest using a PDF-creator, that acts as printer driver.
Should be easy enough to print the plaintext files into PDF and then merge them to the remaining documentation.

Have a look at http://download.cnet.com/1770-20_4-0.html?query=Adobe+PDF+Printer+Driver+Plug+in&searchtype=downloads for drivers.

Comment: It looks like this may be an impossible mission - I'll update the question shortly

Comment: Accepted as the best answer I'm likely to get, though it didn't pan out.

Answer (score 0):

If your code is kept in external files, one way would be to attach the original file(s) as PDF attachments. This could be done with Docbook, LaTeX, DITA, and a few others.

For example, if you are using [this method to include code in Docbook](http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/ExternalCode.html), you can write some code to your XSL customization layer for adding the external file as an attachment to the PDF. As far as I know, this is portable (although I haven't personally tried to open PDF files with attachments in Evince, Okular, Xpdf, etc to see what happens).

If you are processing the Docbook files using even FOP, you should still be able to write something into your customization layer to attach files. See the [section on PDF attachments](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/trunk/output.html). You could even output a link to the attachment below the codeblock in the PDF if you want to make it more discoverable to people.

A similar solution should be possible using LaTeX with the attachfile package.